# Unable to add user to Office 365 or rename user because of existing username

Tags: microsoft-office-365

When changing a users username from @onmicrosoft.com to real domain you get the following error:
 "We're sorry, the user couldn't be edited. Review the user information and try again. Correlation ID"

Or if creating a new user and you get the following error "A user with this name already exists. Use a different name."

But running the cmdlet as described in the following help article does not yield any results:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2428507/you-receive-the-following-error-message-in-the-office-365-portal-a-user-with-this-name-already-exists.-use-a-different-name.

Comment: Did you, or do you do any syncing of user accounts with AD Connect on premise?  You can also connect to Office 365 powershell and use the command `get-msoluser -userprincipalname "<email@address>"` to check for existing users with the same name. Double check your deleted users also and see if anything is in there with the same name - run the same command above but add the `-returndeletedusers` switch.

Answer (score 2):

**Probable cause:**

There is a personal Microsoft account with the same email address, as the one you are trying to add, already present in the AD. This will NOT show up in the cmdlet output.

i.e.
Adding mike@contoso.com (or changing the name from mike@contoso.onmicrosoft.com) will result in an error if Mike has already added his personal Microsoft account mike@contoso.com via the Azure Portal (this will show up in the list as mike_contoso.com#EXT#@contoso.onmicrosoft.com)

**Solution:**

- Delete the personal Microsoft account
- Create the company account with the correct email (or change the current to the correct one)
- Re-add the personal Microsoft account (do you really need it there?)

Answer (score 1):

For me what fixed it was to go into the Office 365-linked Azure AD via portal.azure.com, and from there I changed the problematic user's username to the desired one. After that, I went back to Office 365 Admin and again updated the user's login. This time it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the username, just open the user's properties and use the default domain drop-down to change them from the .onmicrosoft domain to your own domain.